# Android - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, null-pointer

I'm getting a NullPointerException that is breaking the code on this line:

```
if (options.isVisible()) {
```

Here is the block of code:

```
protected static GoogleMap map;
protected static MarkerOptions markerOptions;
private OnMarkerCreateListener listener;

public LazyMarker(GoogleMap map, MarkerOptions options) {
    this(map, options, null);
}

public LazyMarker(GoogleMap map, MarkerOptions options, OnMarkerCreateListener listener) {
    if (options.isVisible()) {
        createMarker(map, options, listener);
    } else {
        this.map = map;
        this.markerOptions = copy(options);
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

I'm guessing it has to do with the MarkerOptions variable but I'm not sure if it's breaking because it is not being initialized?  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Yes! You are passing null reference of `MarkerOptions` when creating a  `LazyMarker` instance.

Comment: If you are using some code, first of all do not modify it in bad ways: `protected static` there were `private` non-static for a good reason. This change is probably the root cause of your problems. Anyway if you use this class directly, send a correct argument when creating `LazyMarker`. Something like `new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(30, 30))`. If you use this class as part of Android Maps Extensions, send a correct arguemtnt to `GoogleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions)`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mzn said Pass a new `MarkerOptions()` and

You should do a null check there

```
if (options!=null &&options.isVisible()) {
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem. It only postpones it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The runtime told you (by throwing an exception) and now you just got human confirmation. You can initialize MarkerOptions with an empty constructor. Pass a new MarkerOptions() if you don't need to make any customization to the default marker.

See this link for documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions

Comment: `MarkerOptions` need to be initialized at least with `LatLng` position.

Answer (score 0):

If you could tell us where you are calling LazyMarker() from and how it looks inside that class, it would be great. I would suggest that you surround the call with a try-catch.

```
try {
    ...
    marker = new LazyMarker(map, options, listener);
    ...
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If this still not works, be sure to check that you are actually defining a MarkerOptions object to the variable.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Surrounding code to catch a `NPE` isn't an answer. The OP needs to find out why the variable is `null`

Comment: Then maybe he is not defining a new MarkerOptions object to the variable? Or maybe he sets it to be null at some point by mistake?

Comment: Possibly, I don't know without knowing how the constructor is being called. But the point is that your answer isn't very effective. Not trying to be a jerk..just trying to help

Comment: Yes. That's a very bad habit. There is no point in catching `RuntimeException`s most of the time. Programming error has to be fixed by modifying the code.